# make a popup demo /intro for a website

Tags: html, popup, demo

I wish to provide a quick demo about the contents of my website and how to use them in a proper way as soon as a user visits my page. I wish to give the demo using a popup type window at the top.

I mean small information boxes informing user about the various steps one by one. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it's fully customisable, or consider using some sort of tool tip idea, when you mouse over a part of the page feedback to the user what the section in question is for (via hovering mouse overs etc).

Comment: hey but i was wishing to have a popup which shows events in a sequence like step 2out of 4 etc... can u give me some such links >/?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is with javascript.

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

know this question is old but try [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

include js/css

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/introjs.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/intro.min.js"></script>
```

then on each item you want to show tutorial add the following

> data-step="1" data-intro="Enter tip text"

```
 <div class="span6" data-step="1" data-intro="Click here for help">
 <div class="span6" data-step="2" data-intro="Click here for home page">
```